# What are the books/blogs on CAD/CAE software development?

Tags: desktop-application, cad

Can you please list the books on CAD/CAE tool development? I remember browsing through a book on some other topic (OOAD or Design Patterns) with all examples in CAD/CAE tool development. Do you know of any such books?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [Geometric Modeling](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0831132981) by Michael Mortenson

  [The NURBS Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3540615458) by Les A. Piegl, Wayne Tiller

  [Curves and Surfaces for CADG: A Practical Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558607374) by Gerald Farin

Answer (score 1):

Apart from books mentioned by Alberto, you should also check [Boundary Representation Modelling Techniques](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1846283124)

It is one of the very few books available on this topic.